# Installed Nvidia driver doesn't run

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to a drivers problems, so don't know anything.

I've tried to install nvidia-dkms-510 and nvidia-driver-510, but after rebooting no results. "Software & Updates" shows nothing at "Additional Drivers" section; "ubuntu-drivers list" has no output.

"nvidia-smi" says "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

So it's not loaded and I don't know how to load it. If you need some additional info, give me commands for it, or which part of "nvidia-bug-report.sh" is needed.

Comment: `cd /lib/firmware` then type `ls | grep -i nvidia` and report back to us

Comment: @darth_epoxy In /lib/firmware/nvidia/ I have directories 510.73.05 gk20a gm* gp* gv100 tegra* tu*

Comment: @guiverc I don't know what kind of information needed so I asked to give me exact commands. I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS, kernel version 5.13.0-51-generic

Comment: You've just provided the release details (20.04 or the 2020-April release) and you're using the HWE kernel (at 20.04.4 it's 5.13) where 20.04 using the GA kernel uses 5.4 for the life of the product.  If interested some details on kernel stack can be read at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack